# "Extra" unwanted first page

Tags: code

I've got a problem that creates an extra first page, that contains one sentence... I can't find the problem to this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onecolumn]{report}

\setlength{\parskip}{4pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}          
\usepackage{amsmath}           
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-25mm}                              
\addtolength{\textheight}{25mm}

\begin{document}

    \title{\textbf{SF1665 för CFATE: Projektrapport \\ Pilbågen}
        \author{Jesper Carlson \and Emil Andersson}
        \date{\today} 
        \titlepic{\includegraphics{kthlogga.png}}
    }

\maketitle

\newpage

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\section{Sammanfattning}
    \label{sec:sammanfattning}

        Problemet vi försöker lösa i vår uppgift är en pilbåge som spänns upp av en
        tråd, där vi söker materialets elasticitetsmodul. För att ta reda på detta är
        en differential ekvation given, med tre stycken begynnelsevärden. Med hjälp av
        Matlab reder vi ut problemet och löser detta.

\tableofcontents

\newpage


\section{Nomenklatur}
    \label{sec:nomenklatur}

\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    {\bf Storheter} & {\bf Namn} & {\bf Enhet} \\
    q & Elasticitetsmodul & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}




\section{Problembeskrivning}
    \label{sec:problembeskrivning}

        Uppgiften är att bestämma formen på pilbågen. Den blir symmetrisk kring
        mittpunkten så det räcker med att behandla högra halvan av intervallet
        $-a \le x \le a$. För utböjningen av $y(x)$ gäller följande differentialekvation:   

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  \displaystyle\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} + q\cdot
  y [1 + (\displaystyle\frac{dy} {dx})^{2}]^{3/2} = 0
\end{equation}

        där storheten q beror av linjalens materialegenskaper som elasticitetsmodul
        och tröghetsmoment.


Randvillkoren är: $y(0)=0.3, y'(0)=0, y(a)=0$. Dessutom finns villkoret att
pilbådens längd är exakt en halvmeter från $x=0$ till $x=a$.

Det blir fråga om ett ickelinjärt randvärdesproblem med två okända konstanter
a och q. Goda startvärden behövs för att de iterativt ska kunna bestämmas.

Börja med att lösa det förenklade problemet då $y'$-termen försummas, för att
sedan kunna utnyttja resultatet som startgissning till det ickelinjära
problemet. Förenklingen ger differentialekvationen $y''+qy=0$ med samma
randvillkor.

        \begin{itemize}
            \item Visa att lösningen kan skrivas $y(x)=0.3cos(\sqrt{q}x)$ och
            ange sambandet mellan $a$ och $q$.
        \end{itemize}


\section{Praktik}
    \label{sec:praktik}

        För att illustrera de teoretiska resultaten i avsnitt~\ref{sec:teori}
        så görs det bäst med ett numeriskt exempel eller en mätserie.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\columnwidth]{stegsvar}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Ange alltid enheter på axlarna.}
  \label{fig:prestanda}
\end{figure}

figur~\ref{fig:prestanda} \includegraphics[width=9mm]{kthlogga.png}

\section{Algoritm}
    \label{sec:algoritm}


För att lösa problemet som är givet följs en algoritm i numrerad ordning.
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] För ett givet värde på $q$, använd de två villkoren vid $x=0$ att
  lösa begynnelsevärdesproblemet.
  \item[2] $a$-värdet erhålls vid kurvans skärningspunkt med $x$-axeln. Bestäm
  denna punkt med stor noggrannhet, interpolation behövs.
  \item[3] Kontrollera därefter hur äl båglängdsvillkoret är uppfyllt. Om för
  dåligt, välj ett nytt $q$-värde och börja om från 1.
\end{itemize}


    \subsection{Algoritm detaljerad}
        \label{sec:algoritm}

            En mer detaljerad beskrivning av den valda algoritmen presenteras. Hur löste
            vi detaljerna?
\section{Noggranhetsbedömning}
    \label{sec:noggranhetsbedömning}


        Hur väl kan man lita på siffrorna i utträkningarna? Vad finns det för
        felgräns?

\section{Resultat}
    \label{sec:resultat}

        Resultaten presenteras

\section{Egen arbetsinsats}
    \label{sec:arbete}


Vad i projektet har du gjort själv, med vilka har vi diskuterar ideér med? 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{latex} Per Jacobsson \textsl{Introduktion till \LaTeX}, Studentlitteratur.
\bibitem{texniccenter} TeXnicCenter. Grafisk editor för \LaTeX~, kan hittas på \textsf{www.texniccenter.org}.
\bibitem{latexmanual} Tobias Oetiker et al. \textsl{The Not So Short
    Introduction to
    \LaTeXe}
  \footnote{\texttt{www.nada.kth.se/datorer/tex/doc/latex/general/lshort.pdf}}.    
\bibitem{matlab} \textsl{Matlab command reference}, kan
  hittas på \textsf{www.matlab.com}.
\end{thebibliography}

\section{Matlab kod}
    \label{sec:matlab}
        \cite{matlab}
            \begin{verbatim}

                Här kommer matlab koden placeras!

            \end{verbatim}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Your example code produces an error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \textyen unavailable in encoding OT1`. Please fix it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: The web site uses UTF-8, but the TeX file `latin1`. The error goes away, if `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is used or if the file is reencoded to match `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`.

Comment: What contains the first page. Can you shorten the example to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Probably the stuff after the title is not quite relevant for the problem.

Comment: A possible problem is some error during processing of the preamble; do you get the `Missing \begin{document}` error?

Comment: How large is `kthlogga.png`? If the image is too large, the title might get moved to the next page.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Too long for a comment.</sub>

The file does not create an empty first page for me. But there are several issues with `\label`:

- `\label{sec:noggranhetsbedömning}`

  "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed., "2.4 Managing references", defines the *key* for `\label{key}`:

  > ... a "key" (consisting of a string of ASCII letters, digits, and punctuation) ...

  Package `babel` adds support for its shorthand characters for use in  `\label` and `\ref` macros. (But there might be packages not yet aware of `babel`'s shorthands.) Thus the following will work:

  ```
  \label{sec:noggranhetsbed"omning}
  ```

  or
      \label{sec:noggranhetsbedoemning}

  Also the character mappings of the slots supported by package `inputenc`' used encoding could be redefined to use `babel` short hand instead of the LaTeX macros. As example `"o` could be used instead of `\"o` for `ö`. Then `ö` could be used inside `\label`. But the procedure is not trivial, because it depends on the used input encodings (which can even be changed inside the document). Therefore I recommend it for experts only, which know what they are doing.
- `` LaTeX Warning: Label `sec:algoritm' multiply defined. `` is caused by:

  ```
  \section{Algoritm}
  \label{sec:algoritm}
  ...
  \subsection{Algoritm detaljerad}
  \label{sec:algoritm}
  ```

  One of the keys `sec:algoritm` needs to be changed.
- `` LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:teori' ``: Probably  section "teori" is not yet written.

Answer (score 0):

The `\maketitle` must be the first command of the document, if you instert blank line, it's add a new paragraph and add extra page. You sould define the author and others stuff into the preambule of your document

Comment: Solved, a little error.

Comment: No, you can have as many empty lines (`\par`) as you wish. The document starts in vertical mode and `\par` has nothing to end a paragraph. Therefore it just have no effect. A new paragraph is only started, if there is something that starts a new paragraph. An empty line (or `\par`) ends a paragraph.